# Cannot use json_encoded array passed back from PHP to an .ajax() function in JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I’m using JQuery and PHP.  I've researched this and the solutions provided work when I simulate the solution in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/muraz/vazy9q35/20/).  But as soon as I put it in my code, it fails. I’m using .ajax() to pass variables to PHP, and PHP is successfully passing back a JSON_encoded array.  My problem is I cannot use the response object, even though I can see its property encoded as a JSON object.  For example, obj.element errors.

This code below works with the object data representing the `json_encoded($php_array)` sent back from PHP (see `var data =` down below.)

```
function solutions() {
  var solution = {
    a: true,
    cfa: c.tf //(c.tf is a constant and equals 10,000)
  };
  
  $.ajax ({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'functions.php',
    data: solution,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $.each(data, function(key, valve){
        console.log(key+":"+value);
      });      
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("Error returning solution ");
    }
  });
}
```

The PHP code:

```
if($_POST['a']) {
    $cfa = $_POST['cfa'];

    if($cfa > 0 && $cfa <= $threshold['cfa0']) {
      $a = $other['a'];
      // additional elseif's through $threshold['cfa6'] and 
      // $other['a6']
    }
    
    if($cfa > 0 && $cfa <= $threshold['cfa0']) {
      $u = $other['u'];
      // additional elseif's through $threshold['cfa6'] and 
      // $other['u6']
    }

    if($cfa > 0 && $cfa <= $threshold['cfa0']) {
      $c = $other['c'];
      // additional elseif's through $threshold['cfa6'] and 
      // $other['c6']
    }

    $aa = array(
      "cfa" => number_format($cfa,0),
      "a" => number_format($a,0),
      "u" => number_format($u,0),
      "c" => number_format($c,0));
    echo json_encode($aa);
```

Console.log(data) shows {"cfa":0,"a":0,"u":3,"c":0}, followed by the same thing but with the results of functions.php {"cfa":10,000,"a":20,000,"u":12,000,"c":13,000}.

I need to use 'a', 'u', and 'c'.  But I get one error:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in {"cfa":"0","a":"0","u":"0","c":"0"} 
    at p (jquery.min.js:2:1104)
```

followed by four entries, all of which are the same

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in {"cfa":10,000,"a":20,000,"u":12,000,"c":13,000} 
    at p (jquery.min.js:2:1104)
```

Side Note: It works if I set `var data = {"cfa":10,000,"a":20,000,"u":12,000,"c":13,000}` and then run `data` run it `$.each` .

```
$.each(data, function(key, valve){
    console.log(key+":"+value);
});
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255607/discussion-on-question-by-hy-ty-cannot-use-json-encoded-array-passed-back-from-p); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.